# Handling a null Connection in finally

Tags: java, connection

I establish a database connection. I then try to make the connection and return if there is an exception.  Further down in the code I have a Finally block that I intend to use as a catch all to close the connection.

```
Connection con = null;
try{
  try{
     con = connectDB();
  }
  catch{
     return;
  }
  ...code
catch{
  return;
}
finally{
    con.close();
}
```

However, if the initial connect fails, it jumps to the Finally block where my con.close() throws a null pointer exception.  What is the best way to get around this?  Is there a way to test if the con is null?  I've tried if(con.isValid(0)) and con.equals(null) and con == null, none of them work.

Answer (score 4):

`Connection` implements `AutoClosable` so you can use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

```
try (Connection con = connectDB()) {
    [some code]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (con.isValid(0))
```

can't work, if `con` is `null`. you would be calling a member of a null-variable, causing a `NullPointerException`.

The same goes for

```
con.equals(null)
```

Now,

```
if ( con == null )
```

does work, but you want the negative comparison:

```
if ( con != null )
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `con != null` or `Objects.nonNull(con)` to check if the connection object is not `null` before closing it inside `finally` block as shown below:

```
Connection con = null;
try{
     con = connectDB();
     //add your code
  catch{
      //log exception
      return;
  } finally {
    if(Objects.nonNull(con)) { //or use con != null
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Or else you can also use try-with-resources (because `Connection` implements [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)) as shown below:

```
try(Connection con = connectDB()) {
   //code
catch {
   return;
}
```